Magento 2 - How to filter on multiselect product attribute with AND condition
I have two custom product attributes. both attribute type is Multiselect. I want a product collection using a filter of both attributes.
I have tried with below solution but it not working.
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
            array(
              array('attribute'=>'configurator_room', 'finset'=>271983),
              array('attribute'=>'configurator_light_location_recommendation', 'finset'=>272001),
          )
        );


You can try addFieldToFilter, using objectmanager just to test obviously not recomended
 <?php
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
    
    $productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get(CollectionFactory::class);
    
    $productCollection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
    $attrCode = 'filter_size';
    $collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter(
    'filter_size', ['finset'=>"197"]->addFieldToFilter('manufacturing_parts', ['finset'=>"27"]);
    print_r($collection->getData());


is this possible to update logic for the entire PLP and search result page, please add your inputs
